# Tools (and applications) for django developer

Tags: python, django

I'm a beginner django developer. And often, when looking for solutions or reading articles on web I find lots of useful django applications, libraries, etc... But I've never met a comprehensive list.

So I ask everyone to share your list of django related stuff you use in your projects. So far I've learnt:

- [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) -- intelligent schema and data migrations
- [Django debug toolbar](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar) -- a configurable set of panels that display various debug information about the current request/response (and SQL!)
- [CPServer](https://github.com/lincolnloop/django-cpserver) -- serving django via CherryPy
- [Treebeard](https://tabo.pe/projects/django-treebeard/) -- a library that implements efficient tree implementations
- [sorl-thumbnails](http://thumbnail.sorl.net/docs/) -- thumbs for your images
- [Haystack Search](http://haystacksearch.org/) -- modular search for django
- [Sentry](http://code.disqus.com/code/projects/sentry.html) -- it will catch any exception thrown by Django and store it in a database
- [Celery with django-celery](http://celeryproject.org/) -- an asynchronous task queue/job queue
- [Lettuce with lettuce.django](http://lettuce.it/index.html) - a very simple BDD tool based on the Cucumber

Your turn

Comment: Why aren't you using the django community site for this? http://www.djangoproject.com/community/

Answer (score 0):

One awesome tool is the PyCharm program that supports Django. It lets you do things like runserver and syncdb from within the app so you don't need to keep switching back and forth to the terminal. Google PyCharm and you should find it.

Answer (score 0):

I find [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) essential to my development process.  The `sqldiff` command alone is incredibly useful.  The django-extensions package requires nothing more than a pip install to have it working on your system.

Answer (score 0):

sorl-thumbnail is nice but I personally prefer [django-imagekit](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-imagekit) for creating thumbnails.